# extract the Time Frame string of the script

Tags: pine-script

in Pine Script, I set the indicator parameter to as such

```
indicator("My Script", overlay = false, timeframe='', max_labels_count = 500)
```

So that I can adjust the script's timeframe. Now in the script itself, I need to assign the timeframe as a string to a variable. What built-in function can I use? Thanks.

I've tried the timeframe.period, which only return the chart's timeframe. but not the script's.